# Item Cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the request SQL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update a database through excel with the following code:

```
Public Sub insertNew()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select


strDB = "i:\Profile\Desktop\DB\Database.accdb"


        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

       cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strDB & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"


       Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

      rs.Open "Project Manager", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

        r = 2 ' the start row in the worksheet

            Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0


                If Range("AD" & r) = "Yes" Then

                   With rs
                   .AddNew 

                   'These fields are on the spreadsheet, transfer will be made to the database
                    .Fields("ID") = Range("A" & r).Value
                    .Fields("Full Name") = Range("C" & r).Value
                    .Fields("SOEID") = Range("B" & r).Value
                    .Fields("SMT") = Range("D" & r).Value
                    .Fields("Manager") = Range("E" & r).Value


                    .Update 
                    End With
                End If

            r = r + 1 ' next row
        Loop
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing

        cn.Close
End Sub
```

The error occurs at the following line:

> .Fields("Full Name") = Range("C" & r).Value

If I comment that line out then the line below gives the same error message. All of these columns are in the table `Project Manager` and I have checked that they are not misspelled etc.

I have never seen this error message before so have no idea where to even begin trouble shooting it, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by placing [ ] around Project manager so the line looked like this:

```
rs.Open "[Project Manager]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
```